# Feed already loaded...Instagram feed not loading

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, instagram-api

When trying to add instagram feed, after obtaining token and adding div to page, page loads, instagram images load quickly then disappear and are replaced by "Feed already loaded..." What am I missing?

I'm following information found on instagram developer site and also this article demonstration https://ariasthompson.com/2018/02/08/adding-instagram-feed-website-without-plugin/ with a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ianphilthompson/aw3Lboue
I've followed all of the steps and am able to briefly view the instagram images on my page. Am I overlooking something?

Thanks for the help!

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=5452392704.c020aaa.a8284c2fa0c64499bf69ee69d91dd7bd&count=9', true);

        request.onload = function(container) {
          if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            for (var i=0;i < data.data.length;i++) {
                var container = document.getElementById('insta-feed');
                var imgURL = data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
                console.log(imgURL);
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute('class','instapic');
                container.appendChild(div);
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute('src',imgURL)
                div.appendChild(img);
            }

            console.log(data);
          } else {
          }
        };
        request.onerror = function() {
          // There was a connection error of some sort
        };
        request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why this happened. My best guess is that there was something in the theme I was playing with that was causing this issue. I’m working with Shopify. I made a new theme from scratch and the only js included is this bit of code. And now it’s working perfectly. 
Wish I had a better answer- but oh well :)